# Como rodar script npm no heroku em produção?

Tags: node.js, script, npm, heroku, sequelize-js

Preciso utilizar as migrations do [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) em uma aplicação NodeJS que ja esta em produção no Heroku, mas não sei como adicionar os scripts no `package.json` para que as migrações do Banco de Dados sejam executadas sempre, através de script npm, pelo Heroku.

Alguém já passou por isso? Preciso fazer algum passo especial?